# Where can I find more information on the Gloaming Court/Gloaming Fey?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore

Recently I have stumbled upon some lore that refers to the "Maiden of the Moon", who is apparently one of the "Gloaming Court". There seems to be very little information out there on the web generally, and this is not something I've encountered in 5e (the only edition that I really know much about) beyond the occasional reference (e.g. one of the Circle of Dreams druid's class features briefly mentions it in passing).

I assume that 4e will most likely have the most information given that the Feywild was introduced in 4e, but if there are any references to the Gloaming Fey/Court in earlier editions (or if I've overlooking something in 5e), then **any lore from any edition is welcome.**

Just to be clear, **my focus is on the Gloaming Fey/Court generally**, not necessarily the Maiden of the Moon specifically (although I'm also interested to know more about her as well *as part of* the general information about the Gloaming Fey/Court).

**What I'm looking for is lore, not gameplay or mechanics**; I'm hoping that an answer will say "there's a big chuck of information in *<*insert book name here*>*, and also in these Dragon magazines *<*insert various magazine numbers here*>*", ideally with page numbers or at least section headings. I'm not necessarily expecting large quotes trying to compile all of that information here.

---

Related (but broader than what I'm looking for): [Where can I find more lore about fey and eladrin?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152986/35259)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In fifth edition**, the Gloaming Court is another name for the Unseelie Court, according to

> [T]he Queen of Air and
> Darkness, ruler of the Gloaming Court, leads the unseelie fey. —*5e Dungeon Master's Guide, pg. 49*

so you could simply look for information on the Unseelie Court, which is easily available.

**In fourth edition**, however, there is no Unseelie Court, per

> [The terms "seelie" and "unseelie"] are meaningless to the residents of the Feywild themselves. —*4e Manual of the Planes, pg. 38*

but there is a Gloaming Court, described on that page. This is the best source of lore I could find.

There are brief references to the Gloaming fey on pages 12 and 134 of *Heroes of the Feywild*, and in Dragon magazine #428 (section "The Wild Hunt").

Dragon magazine #382 includes a description of the Gloaming Path, associated with the Gloaming Court.

Comment: Thank you for this answer; _Manual of the Planes, Heroes of the Feywild_, and those two dragon magazines have helped me immensely in understanding the various fey courts and how the Gloaming Court fits into all of this.

Comment: There's also, I recently discovered, a couple of paragraphs on p. 60 of Dragon magazine #374 about the Gloaming Fey, mostly about the Prince of Hearts, an archfey of the Gloaming Court.

Comment: One slight correction; the Unseelie were added to the 4e's Court of Stars in Heroes of the Feywild in a sidebar, after Manual of the Planes previously established the terms "seelie" and "unseelie" as mortal terms to designate "honorable/friendly fey" vs. "dishonorable/unfriendly fey". The Unseelie Court is made up of fey who have embraced shadow magic, a power emanating from the Shadowfell that is the root of necromancy and nethermancy, and which typically has a powerful morally corruptive effect on its practitioners. As a result, Unseelie fey tend to be mutated and malevolent.

Comment: @cjjscrawfordbigpondcom If we're looking at the same sidebar, it says that the Unseelie fey "have no true representative among the Court of Stars". I got the impression from that sidebar that the Unseelie weren't a faction, but rather a loose description for some of the less pleasant fey, consistent with their description in Manual of the Planes.